# Массивы в Python

Tags: python, массивы

Как реализовать запись в массив каждые 0,5 секунд без прерывания основной программы?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть модуль [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#module-signal).

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)
    raise OSError("Couldn't open device!")

# Set the signal handler and a 5-second alarm
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(5)

# This open() may hang indefinitely
fd = os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)

signal.alarm(0)          # Disable the alarm
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/152628)

Comment: Я понимаю, что документация по Python вряд ли куда-то денется, но ответ все-таки стоит расширить.

Comment: Учту в дальнейшем.